# Serialization of vector of polymorph objects in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, polymorphism, cereal

I am looking for a nice way to serialize a certain class in C++. The main feature of this class is a list/vector/collection of `std::shared_ptr<base_class>`, where there can be different subclasses of `base_class`.

So far, I have tried implementing this using the cereal library with initial success. The generated JSON file looks like

```
{
    "value0": [
        {
            "polymorphic_id": 2147483649,
            "polymorphic_name": "DerivedClassOne",
            "ptr_wrapper": {
                "id": 2147483649,
                "data": {
                    "value0": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "polymorphic_id": 2147483650,
            "polymorphic_name": "DerivedClassTwo",
                "ptr_wrapper": {
                "id": 2147483650,
                "data": {
                    "value0": 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess this is fine for use cases where humans are not involved. However, the reason why I look at this feature is that users can write their own (configuration) files such as the following example:

```
{
     "value0": [
         {
             "DerivedClassOne": {
                 "MemberOfDerivedClassOne": 1
              }
         }, 
         {
             "DerivedClassTwo": {
                 "MemberOfDerivedClassTwo": 1
              }
         }
    ]
}
```

where `DerivedClassOne` and `DerivedClassTwo` are subclasses of the common `base_class`.

Is this possible? I am not asking for complete solutions, of course. But comments on the possibility and reasonability of such an approach would be very helpful.

**EDIT 1:** I heard good things about cereal, hence I am using it for those tests. I would be happy with any other modern C++ header only library. Implementing own serialization functions from scratch can be seen as last resort.

**EDIT 2:** For cereal, the question boils down to: Is there a nice way to serialize polymorph objects without the `polymorphic_id`, `ptr_wrapper`, or `id` fields (which are not very user friendly IMHO)?

Comment: I have a similar application and would be grateful for any pointers!

Comment: Add serialization functions to the base class and make them virtual.  Let the children implement them.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Are you suggesting implementing own serialization functions from scratch? While I would be willing to do this as last resort, I'd prefer to base on an existing library.

Comment: I have not used the cereal library.  Polymorphism looks like it would solve your issue.  Verify how you can use cereal library and inheritance.